# Implementing a user defined aggregation function to be used in RelationalGroupedDataset.agg() using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

It seems like you can aggregate multiple columns like this:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().textFile(inputFile);
List<Row> result = df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(sum(df.col("price")), avg(df.col("weight")))
  .collectAsList();
```

Now, I want to write my own custom aggregation function instead of `sum` or `avg`. How can I do that?

The [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-user-defined-aggregate-functions) shows how to create a custom aggregation function. But that one is registered and then used in the SQL and I don't think if it can be used in the `.agg()` function. Since `agg` accepts `Column` instances and the custom aggregation function is not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class `GeometricMean` which extends `UserDefinedAggregationFunction`, then you can use it like this (taken from https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html) :

```
// Create an instance of UDAF GeometricMean.
val gm = new GeometricMean

// Show the geometric mean of values of column "id".
df.groupBy("group_id").agg(gm(col("id")).as("GeometricMean")).show()
```

Should be easy to transleta this into Java

Comment: Thanks, just one question. Since I'm not fluent in Scala, `gm(col("id"))` in Scala translates into Java's `gm.apply(col("id"))`, right?